# java Stream() showing error while using .replaceAll() method on list of String

Tags: java, list, java-stream

I have a database of movies which contains things like, title, year, list of actors, list of producers and list of directors. I am trying to develop a method that takes the actor's real name and replaces it with actor's stage name as stored in the database. I came up with following code.

```java
void actorNameChange()
    {
        Scanner s = new Scanner(System.in);
        System.out.println("Actor Real name : ");
        String realName = s.nextLine();
        System.out.println("Actor stage Name : ");
        String stageName = s.nextLine();
        List<Movie> movies = data.stream().filter(m -> m.getActors().contains(stageName)).collect(toList());

           movies.stream().map(movie -> movie.getActors().stream().sorted(st -> st.replaceAll(realName,stageName)).toArray();
//i am gaetting error here at st.replaceAll() -> method doesn't found
    }
```

Comment: what should i use to replace the string ?

Comment: do you want to set `realname` of actor for `Movie` object ?

Comment: what is the return type of `getActors()` in `Movie` class?

Comment: Okay your question is really not clear you need to add some input and output example. what does this method `getActors() ` returns and what do you want on top of it ?

Comment: No, i want to change stagename that is already stored in database in List<String> actor in Movie class.

Comment: so you want to replace name in `List<String>` ?

Comment: getActor() returns List<String> that contains different names Of Actores. Suppose user pass RealName as "Michael Caine" and Actor's  stageName is stored In List<String>  Actor as "Maurice Micklewhite". i want to change stagename with Realname.

Comment: @ShivamPrajapati are you in an iterative way try to perform `for (Movie movie : movies) {
            movie.getActors().replaceAll(m -> m.replace(stageName, realName));
        }`?

Comment: `m -> m.getActors().contains(stageName)` ← Are you sure you didn’t mean to write `m -> m.getActors().contains(realName)`?  Your question seems to indicate that you want to search for a real name, then replace it with a stage name.

Comment: @VGR yes exactly that i want to do

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could use a simple `forEach` with [`List#replaceAll`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/13/docs/api/java.base/java/util/List.html#replaceAll(java.util.function.UnaryOperator)) to update your existing collection such as:

```
data.forEach(movie -> movie.getActors().replaceAll(m -> m.replace(realName, stageName)));
```